# Which of the following is a maximal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Which of the following is a maximal ideal?
>
> $1. (3) \subset \mathbb{Q}[x] $
>
> $2. (3,x) \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$
>
> $3. (x) \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$
>
> $4. (x) \subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$
>
> $5. (3) \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$

I'm so confused about maximal ideal and quotient ring stuff. So going through some examples might help me clarify the concepts. I would really appreciate it if you could check my understanding.

First of all, is $(3) = ${$3r : r \in R$} ? I see some notes that treat $<x>$ and $(x)$ the same way. But $<x>$ is used to represent a cyclic group. Isn't it?

1. $(3)$ represents all polynomials of which the coefficients are multiple of 3. But since this ideal is in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ there can be other ideals such as (0.5) which includes (3).
2. $(3,x)$ represents all the polynomials that are proportional to $x$ such as $x, x^2, x+x^3$, etc, and all polynomials that have coefficients with a multiple of $3$. So the only ideal that includes this one is $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So this one is maximal.
3. $(x)$ represents all the polynomials that are proportional to $x$. But $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ and this is not a field. So my the theorem "$R/I$ is a filed iff I is maximal", this one is not maximal
4. Unlike #$3$, $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field. So it's maximal.
5. Unlike #$1$, it's in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So this one is maximal.

Comment: 1. What is an ideal generated by a unit?
2. If you divide (x), will there be polynomials left?
3. and 4. are correct.
5. What is the inverse of $x$?

Comment: Why don't you apply $R/M$ is a field iff M is maximal also to the other items?

Comment: @DietrichBurde that's the part I got confused also becausee I wasn't sure about the exact definition of , for example, ideal  (3).  By the way, when you check if it's a field or not, do you check if every element is unit? Is that the easiest way?

Comment: @MariusS.L. 1. It's the ring itself, $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ Oh so it's not maximal because maximal ideal can't be the ring itself.   2. yes,  constant terms?   3. $x^{-1}$? why should I consider this case? Can you provide some more hints?

Comment: jun, it is easier to give an isomorphism to a field, which you suspect it will be it. So, for example $K[x]/(x)\cong K$, by using the homomorphism lemma. No need to check for units.

Comment: 2. You wrote $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which is not "constant terms" and no field. If you divide $(x)$ you are left with $\mathbb{Z}$ and then divide $(3)$ you get $\mathbb{Z}_3$ which is a field, but not $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ as you wrote. Note: Dividing first $(x)$ and then $(3)$ works in this case, because they are coprime. It is not true in general. 3. Yes you are left with $x$ in the quotient ring. If that would be a field, it had to have an inverse. But $x^{-1}$ is nowhere even closely contained in the ring.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde The question for the units was a pedagogic one. A field  contains only units plus 0, so to observe field or ask for units are virtually exactly the same question.

Comment: @MariusS.L. I don't think so. I believe, it was really meant as an alternative to the homomorphism lemma. And I think, one should definitely use this lemma here.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde Sure. I just meant that units or not is a quick way to decide whether the factor ring is a field or not. One can immediately see that if e.g. $x$ is an element of $R/I$, then it cannot be a field since none of the rings used $K(x)$. (I hopefully made no mistakes, esp. as your father was my algebra teacher ;-))

Comment: Do you already know the theorem that $M$ is maximal in $R\iff R/M$ is a field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(x)$ and $\langle x\rangle$  in this context mean the same thing: the principal ideal generated by $x$, and yes that's $(x)=\{xr\mid r\in R\}$.

1. You've come to the wrong conclusion. The thing to notice here is that $3$ is a unit in $\mathbb Q[x]$, so the ideal it generates is the whole ring.
2. You've come to the right conclusion, but without justification. "(3,) represents all the polynomials that are proportional to  such as ,2,+3, etc, and all polynomials that have coefficients with a multiple of 3. " To me it sounds like you are describing $(3x)$.  Rather, it means that everything is of the form $3r+xs$ for some $r,s \in R$.  Here it's good advice to try to compute the quotient using the "third isomorphism theorem."
3. You did fine on this one.
4. Also fine on this one.
5. No, check again. You can prove this one is isomorphic to $F_3[x]$ where $F_3$ is the field of three elements.